# JS event listener to handle user button push?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-handling

I have something like this :

```
div style='cursor: pointer;' onClick='myFunction(" . $_SESSION['pseudos'][$key] . ")'
```

that is supposed to enable users input while the game (in js) is playing. The user is supposed to clic on 1 out of X how those div to chose which char to kill. However the js doesn't stop and wait for an input. Any idea ?

My function js looks like this :

```
function myFunction(foo) {
    if (foo === null){
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        foo = myFunction();
    }
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
foo = myFunction();
```

is invoking `myFunction` immediately. So, unless `myFunction` returns another function that you want your button hooked up to, the line should be:

```
foo = myFunction;
```

Comment: What...? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: No, the fact that changing what you assign to `foo` in the event handler has no bearing on what is returned outside the scope. This looks more like a https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1541563 to me.